# Why the implementation of 3D rotation matrix will change the magnitude of vector?

Tags: matrix, vector, rotation, arduino, rotational-matrices

I have problem when I am trying to apply the rotational matrix on a gravity vector (obtained and stored from a static accelerometer) when the device is moving around with certain rotation (yaw, pitch, roll). The rotation matrix should not change the magnitude of the vector, but in my case, the magnitude of the vector is changing for every iteration. The code below shows the rotational matrix I used:

averageA contains a constant gravity vector, angleypr contains the yam,pitch and roll angle calculated using gyroscope, magnetometer, accelerometer.

```
temp[0]=averageA[0];
temp[1]=averageA[1];
temp[2]=averageA[2];
//Yaw   
temp[0]=cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[0]+sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[1];
temp[1]=-sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[0]+cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[1];
temp[2]=temp[2];   
//pitch    
temp[0]=temp[0];  
temp[1]=(cos(angleypr[1]*pi/180))*temp[1]+(sin(angleypr[1]*pi/180))*temp[2];
temp[2]=(-sin(angleypr[1]*pi/180))*temp[1]+cos(angleypr[1]*pi/180))*temp[2];    
//roll   
temp[0]=(cos(angleypr[2]*pi/180))*temp[0]-(sin(angleypr[2]*pi/180))*temp[2];
temp[1]=temp[1];  
temp[2]=(sin(angleypr[2]*pi/180))*temp[0]+(cos(angleypr[2]*pi/180))*temp[2];
gravity[0]=temp[0];
gravity[1]=temp[1];
gravity[2]=temp[2];
```

a simple example of the problem I am facing now:

```
temp[0]=cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*20+sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*30;
temp[1]=-sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*20+cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*30;
temp[2]=50;

temp[0]=cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[0]+sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[1];
temp[1]=-sin(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[0]+cos(angleypr[0]*pi/180)*temp[1];
temp[2]=temp[2];
```

I apply the same yaw rotation matrix on a vector [20,30,50] for twice, the 1st rotation give me a constant magnitude but the the second one end up with varying value for every iteration.

Please let me know where I have done wrongly, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd remove the lines that do temp[x] = temp[x] for a start. They're redundant. Then, debug the values coming out each time you amend the temp vector values. You may require a separate temp vector for each of yaw, pitch and roll and combine the effects together for your final vector.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ManoDestra. I'll remove the redundant part, but I don't really understand the suggestion about a separate temp vector for each rotation, do you mind elaborate more on than?

Comment: Create variables something like yaw[0], yaw[1], yaw[2], pitch[0], pitch[1], pitch[2] and roll[0], roll[1], roll[2]. Then update each and combine the effects in your final resultant vector. You don't have to do this, but it may help you debug where it's going wrong by picking apart your problem into smaller problems that can be isolated and debugged separately.

Comment: Alright, I'll try and see what I could do. Probably you could look at the edited  question above because that example is exactly the problem that I am facing now. I am using the same matrices to perform the rotation, but 1st one give a constant magnitude while 2nd one produce a varying magnitude.

Comment: @ManoDestra thanks for your suggestion! That's really the problem, I didn't put extra variable to store the vector I got for every rotation, hence the temp value always got wrong update.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. Easier to start with smaller steps and put them all together, rather than applying multiple transformations to a single variable. Harder to see where the logic could be going awry. Glad you got that fixed :)